# A way to declare and clone a cloneable (#[derive(Clone)]) struct with a type parameter and a field that is an Arc of an uncloneable type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, clone, cloneable

I would like to have a cloneable struct with a type parameter that is uncloneable used for a field that is of type Arc. It looks like Rust requires all type parameters for a cloneable struct to be cloneable too. Without a type parameter, it is possible to declare a cloneable struct with an uncloneable field that is an Arc.

Here is the code that shows:

1. A cloneable struct with a type parameter that is also cloneable.
2. A cloneable struct that does not have a type parameter and has a field that is an Arc of an uncloneable type.

I think it is unnecessary to require the type parameter to be cloneable if it is used in a field that is an Arc<> of that type.

My specific case is a multi threaded pool of resources - I do not want to require my resource to be cloneable. The pool uses `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>` as a way to store resources. Is there a way to make the pool cloneable and keep the T uncloneable.

Is the solution to manually implement `clone()` method and not use `#[derive(Clone)]`?

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::clone::Clone;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ContainerWithGenerics<T> {
    contained: Arc<T>
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ValueCloneable {
    value: i32
}


#[derive(Clone)]
struct ContainerWithoutGenerics {
    contained: Arc<ValueNotCloneable>
}

struct ValueNotCloneable {
    value: i32
}


fn main() {
    let container0 = ContainerWithGenerics { contained: Arc::new(ValueCloneable { value: 1i32 }) }.clone();
    let container1 = ContainerWithoutGenerics { contained: Arc::new(ValueNotCloneable { value: 1i32 }) }.clone();
}
```

Comment: You can `impl Clone for SomeType` like all other traits.

Comment: Thanks. So basically it is a limitation of the #[derive(Clone)], right? A manual implementation of the Clone trait will work?

Comment: Also take a look at https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/latest/index.html which allows for more flexible derivation.

Comment: @AntonYudin just fyi the example you posted does compile.

Comment: Cafce, thanks. That was intentional. The problem arises when you remove #[derive(Clone)] from ValueCloneable.